# wordpress custom menu for different page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am trying to use a custom menu on my landingpage.

I used this code:

```
<?php
function change_wp_nav_menu_args($args = ''){
    $pageID = get_the_id();
    if($pageID == '63') //custom menu for site with id 63
    {
        $args['menu'] = 'homepage';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'change_wp_nav_menu_args' );
?>
```

It works fine, but not only the main menu changes.
The footer menu changes also.
But the footer menu should be the same on every page.

How can I affect this?

Comment: It sounds like your issue isn't really changing the menu on a different page - you've solved that bit - but using different menus for header and footer? I assume you're using the default WordPress menu widgets? I'd be surprised if there wasn't something you could hook that e.g. gets called each time the menu is rendered rather than once per page, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This code fixed my problem:

```
<?php
        add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'bb_wp_nav_menu_args' );
            function bb_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
                // change the menu in the Header menu position
                if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' && is_page('63') ) { 
                    $args['menu'] = '6'; // 32 is the ID of the menu we want to use here
                }
                return $args;
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its great that you find your answer, but it's a suggestion to make the code dynamic rather set the menu value as static [ **$args['menu']='6'** ].

Suggestion :

Create a Meta Box [ Dropdown with list of menu ] for Page with the Label Menu. And use the Menu Id for the **wp_nav_menu** .

For Dropdown [ listing Menus ]

```
function your_menus()
{
    $menu_arr=NULL;
    $menus=get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
    $menu_arr['your-nomenu']='Default';
    foreach ( $menus as $menu ){
        $menu_arr[$menu->slug]=$menu->name;
    }
    return $menu_arr;
}//end of function
```

For Nav Menus : [ _your_page_menu : meta name ]. You can place the code inside a function and called it in Header or you can place this code directly into the header.

```
     $page_menu_name=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_your_page_menu',true)==''?'your-nomenu':get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_your_page_menu',true);
                if($page_menu_name==='your-nomenu')
                {
                    wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'  => 'primary','menu_id'=> 'main-menu','container'=>false,'fallback_cb'=>'','menu_class'=>'main-navigation'));
                }
                else
                {
                    wp_nav_menu(array('menu_id'=> 'main-menu' , 'container'=>false, 'menu'=>$page_

menu_name,'fallback_cb'=>'','menu_class'=>'main-navigation'));
            }
```

Hope it helps you.